# Semantic Search example from AdventureWorks database of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to implement semantic search of SQL Server. To see an example, I downloaded AdventureWorks2012 (An 'almost' step by step guide is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/find-similar-and-related-documents-with-semantic-search?view=sql-server-2017). The error says that @CandidateID and @MatchedID have to be declared

I tried to declare those ID, instead of getting the error or a result I get an empty table.

```
SELECT TOP(10) KEY_TBL.matched_document_key AS Candidate_ID  
FROM SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE  
    (  
    HumanResources.JobCandidate,  
    Resume,  
    @CandidateID  
    ) AS KEY_TBL  
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.score DESC;  
GO 

SELECT TOP(5) KEY_TBL.keyphrase, KEY_TBL.score  
FROM SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE  
    (  
    HumanResources.JobCandidate,  
    Resume, @CandidateID,  
    Resume, @MatchedID  
    ) AS KEY_TBL  
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.score DESC;  
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare these variables and assign values. Only you know the data type of these keys.For example:

```
declare @CandidateID int = 6754,
@MatchedID  int = 4321
```

IDs contain real ids from your indexed table.